# Missing websocket messages during full page reload

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, websocket

I have a node.js websocket server that sends out all received messages to all connected clients (standard stuff). However, this is not a SPA app but a traditional app where the page is being fully refreshed upon each action.

The problem is that a websocket message is being sent to the client while a client is waiting for the page to reload. This causes the client to miss the websocket message because it happened in the middle of the page being reloaded before a websocket connection was established.

This wouldn't be a problem if the application was a SPA but since it's a traditional app this becomes a problem. I'm wondering what is the best practice to work around this problem?

Comment: Even in spa you got this problem. As a workaround you can store the messages (or state) somewhere else and fetch them after reload

Comment: What's your use case?